# Security concerns regarding cookies, code injection, etc

Tags: php, security, cookies

I'm using PHP to set cookies and am wondering what security risks exist around cookies.

For example is code injection possible, like can someone set a cookie to `mail(blah, blah, blah);` and send spam from my server? Or set a cookie to `file_get_contents('secretfile.txt');` to read sensitive system files?

I'm assuming that it depends on how the cookie is used, like this would obviously be stupid:

```
<?php
    exec($_COOKIE['cmd']);
?>
```

However, is using cookies to just set input values secure without sanitization?

Comment: This `exec($_COOKIE['cmd'])` is scaring the crap out of me ... gonna have nightmares for the rest of my life, thanks for that!

Comment: He said that this would be stupid, but have seen like this with $_GET, which is even better to exploit. Less work. :)

Comment: @YUNOWORK Launching Firecookie is too much work. I prefer `exec($_GET['cmd'])`.

Comment: I hate the term "sanitization". It often suggests that underlying code was written with the assumption that you can "fix" insecure input and it becomes magically "safe" for any imaginable context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is **not**. You can edit the values of cookies like of GET or POST Parameter.

Firebug is able to do this in Firefox and Chrome got the native Debugger in this,
so also validate the content of your cookie.

This is a common mistake:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['lang'])){
   $lang=$_COOKIE['lang'];
}else{
   $lang="english";
}

include ("translation/".$lang.".html");
```

This would allow in circumstances a **Local File Inclusion** (LFI), since the content of $_COOKIE['lang'] can be modified.

Comment: I feel such a use of cookie data is just as stupid as the `exec` example I gave. I'm wondering if there is anything unsafe about cookies beyond such obvious exploits. Like whether a simple `echo $_COOKIE['name'];` is exploitable.

Comment: Yes. This allows you to execute a XSS Attack. For more information read there: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29

However, it would effect only the system of the user, so it would be only a risk if different user use the system in something like a internet café. With the correct cookie settings it would effect otherwise only the person of the cookie.

Answer (score 2):

Cookies are as secure as user input. You should be very careful with them.

Comment: So it's safe to assume that cookies are no more and no less secure than GET and POST data then?

Comment: Yep, because users can modify their cookies. You should not use cookies to store informations like password.